# Какие есть способы связать 2 сервиса в ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, шаблоны-проектирования, события

Необходимо сделать доработку в систему где присутствует самописный IoC.
Есть сервис D который вызывается из api1 -> D и в нем храниться важное состояние из-за этих вызовов. Есть сервис Е, работает из api2 -> E, **он должен уведомлять при запросах api2 сервис D**(именно тот инстанс D который используется в api1, так как нам важно его состояние).

Я собираюсь подправить самописный IoC передать в конструктор сервиса D сервис Е, вот так D(IE). Дальше сделать подписку в конструкторе IE.event += this.NecessaryMethod;

**Хочу узнать есть ли другие более подходящие способы связать эти сервисы в такой ситуации?**

Вопрос возник из-за нежелания разбираться и дописывать IoC (который делал не я).

Comment: из вашего описания не понятно ничего. Будет проще, если вы добавите код. Также поясните, что конкретно вы называете api сервисом?

Comment: api - наследник класса ApiController, сервис - класс который используем в api (он несет в себе бизнес логику), кода будет слишком много и будут отвлекать не значительные детали. Тут я описал формально и думаю что этих абстракций должно хватить.

Comment: если у вас 2 WebApi проекта, развернутые в разных местах, то связать их просто через event handler не получится

Comment: Подправил, все в 1 проекте.

Comment: ну тогда вы можете либо да, сделать событиями, либо передать сервис D в конструктор сервиса E и в нужный момент вызывать сервис D напрямую, или вы можете организовать шину сообщений и пусть E публикует сообщение, а D считывает. Выбирать вам. Что  лучше в данной ситуации знаете только вы.

Comment: Шина сообщений - RabbitMQ или есть другие варианты?

Comment: конечно [есть](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+in+memory+event+bus) другие [варианты](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+in+memory+event+aggregagtor) передачи [сообщений](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html), но ради одного события из добавлять не стоит, разве что если у вас они и так уже есть. Я бы на вашем месте сначала попробовал бы D прокинуть в конструктор E, если не получится, то тогда думал бы над event handler'ом, если он не прокатит, то тогда уже тяжелая арта - брокеры событий/сообщений

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно.

> Я собираюсь подправить самописный IoC передать в конструктор сервиса D сервис Е, вот так D(IE). Дальше сделать подписку в конструкторе IE.event += this.NecessaryMethod;

Главное чтобы не забыли отписаться потом, и чтобы сервис Е был синглтоном, иначе "каши не сваришь".